# Load a csv file and compare it with other files Scilab

Tags: csv, scilab

How do I load a csv file and compare it with a data file and append the data file with new information from the csv file

```
function doSomethingWithCSVdata(CSV_data)
    disp(CSV_data);
endfunction

csv_files = listfiles('*.csv');

for i=1:size(csv_files,1)

    disp('Opening file: '+csv_files(i))
    csvData = csvRead(csv_files(i),ascii(9), [], 'string');

    doSomethingWithCSVdata(csvData);
end
```

Used to open the csv file but not sure how to go about comparing it with the Grades.dat

Comment: Please specify your question further. What kind of data (file), what kind of comparison. What problem are you trying to solve? What did you try?

Comment: The data file has a file extension .dat (Grades.dat) and it has 3 fields |student number|,|grade| and |year|. The csv file has fields |student number| and |grade| im trying to compare if they is any new students in the csv file to be added to the Grades.dat file and then update the Grades.dat with info from the csv file.